# Access last insert ID mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-insert

I'm having issues with accessing the insert_id. It is currently returning 0

```
function database_connection(){
    $insight_database = mysqli_connect( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME );
    if ( $insight_database ) {
        return $insight_database;
    }
}
function database_tables(){
    $insight_tables = "CREATE TABLE posts (
            ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
            post_author bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
            post_date datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            post_date_gmt datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            post_content longtext NOT NULL,
            post_title text NOT NULL,
            post_excerpt text NOT NULL,
            post_status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'publish',
            post_password varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
            post_name varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
            post_parent bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
            post_type varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'post',
            post_mime_type varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            KEY post_name (post_name($max_index_length)),
            KEY type_status_date (post_type,post_status,post_date,ID),
            KEY post_parent (post_parent),
            KEY post_author (post_author)
        )
        ENGINE = INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
    ";   
    database_connection()->multi_query($insight_tables);
}
database_tables();
$query = "INSERT INTO posts (post_title, post_content) VALUES ('". $args->post_title ."', '". $args->post_content ."')";
$result = mysqli_query(database_connection(), $query);
$id = database_connection()->insert_id;
```

$id seems to return zero.

My INSERT is working.

According to PHP docs, insert_id returns the "ID generated by a query (usually INSERT) on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute."

Comment: `database_connection()->xxx` creates a new connection object.    Shouldn't you  call it just once to get an object and assign it to a variable, then use that variable in the rest of the code, passing it to other functions like `database_tables`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put database connection to a variable, then start to use it.

like:

```
$db = database_connection();
$query = "INSERT INTO posts (post_title, post_content) VALUES ('". $args->post_title ."', '". $args->post_content ."')";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$id = $db->insert_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new database connection and getting `$id` against that new connection.  Use `database_connection` to return a db connection and use that going forward (and have some error checking too).  You should also look into PDO connections.